# detours vs MinHook for DLL injection

Tags: c++, hook, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I have succefully hooked a gog game (DRM free) with this code:

```
bool WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    static HMODULE libogg_ori = nullptr;

    int FFBInitDelayInMillliseconds;

    char* DLLFileName;

    std::string DLLFile = "libogg_ori.dll";

    switch (dwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Load dll

         // Initialize config File
        Local_InitConfigComplete = Init_Config();

        // Delay for timer that initialize the Force Feedback
        FFBInitDelayInMillliseconds = Config.FFBDelayBeforeInit * 1000;

        DLLFileName = R"(libogg_ori.dll)";

        if (FS::File_Exist(DLLFileName))
        {
            LF::Log_Update("File DLL exit");
            // Load the System DLL
            d3d9dll = LoadLibraryA(DLLFileName);

            if (d3d9dll == NULL)
                LF::Log_Update("Load DLL error");
        }
        else
        {
            LF::Log_Update("File DLL not exist");
        }


        // Initilize Detour
        if (Local_InitConfigComplete)
            Local_InitConfigComplete = Init_Detour();


        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

        // Close the DLL

        LF::Log_Update("Closing session ...");
        LF::Log_Update("Release hook in progress ...");

        // unhook
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        // this will hook the sound function
        DetourDetach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookSoundFunction, &HookSoundFileSub);

        // this will hook the damage function (if present in configuration)
        if (AddressOfHookDamageFunction>0)
            DetourDetach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookDamageFunction, &HookDamageSub);

        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
            LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_DONE);
        else
            LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_ERROR, "Warning Hooking not relased.");

        LF::Log_Update("Session closed.");

        break;
    }

    return true;
    }
    
    
    
    
    bool Init_Detour()
{
    // Initialize Detours
    // we will find the function/s to hook with IDA pro.

    try
    {
    
        LF::Log_Update("Initialize Hooking ...");
                                                        
        AddressOfHookSoundFunction = std::strtoul(Config.GameFileSoundOffsetPos.c_str() ,NULL,16); // BattleZoneRedux 0x43AA30

         if (Config.GameFileDamageOffsetPos.size() > 1)
             AddressOfHookDamageFunction = std::strtoul(Config.GameFileDamageOffsetPos.c_str(), NULL, 16); // BattleZoneRedux 0x49B430

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    
        // this will hook the sound function
        DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookSoundFunction, &HookSoundFileSub);

        // If is present a offset for hook the damage
        if (AddressOfHookDamageFunction!=0)
            DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookDamageFunction, &HookDamageSub);


       if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
       {
           LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_DONE);
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_ERROR, "Hooking not initilizing.");
           return false;
       }

        
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_ERROR, "Error while initialize Detour.");
        return false;
    }

    
}
```

to do it I have found a custom version of libogg.dll and d3d9.dll (DLL injection). Both work perfectly.

But when I used the some code to another GOG game with DRM free, to inject it with libogg.dll the game crash always on this row:

```
DetourDetach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookSoundFunction, &HookSoundFileSub);
```

In all my test with the game that work, never crash in this row even if AddressOfHookSoundFunction is relative to a non-existent address.

In short independently by AddressOfHookSoundFunction and HookSoundFileSub that second game crash always.

Here the difference between the two games:

1. The first was made in 2017 and the second was made in 2018 by the some software house.
2. If I disassambly with IDA the first game I see always sub_xxxxxx , but in the second game sometimes I see the real name of the functions and not the address. So I suppose it was done by a more recent visual c++ version, and for this reason it may not work.

On many forums the people suggest to use MinHook becouse is better than detours, but I don't known why and if this is true for all cases.

Can someone have the some experience in situations like this ?

If the solution is use minhook, can someone help me to re-write this code:

```
AddressOfHookSoundFunction = std::strtoul(Config.GameFileSoundOffsetPos.c_str() ,NULL,16); // BattleZoneRedux 0x43AA30

         if (Config.GameFileDamageOffsetPos.size() > 1)
             AddressOfHookDamageFunction = std::strtoul(Config.GameFileDamageOffsetPos.c_str(), NULL, 16); // BattleZoneRedux 0x49B430

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        // this will hook the sound function
        DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookSoundFunction, &HookSoundFileSub);

        // If is present a offset for hook the damage
        if (AddressOfHookDamageFunction!=0)
            DetourAttach(&(LPVOID&)AddressOfHookDamageFunction, &HookDamageSub);


       if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
       {
           LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_DONE);
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           LF::Log_Update(LOG_FLAG_ERROR, "Hooking not initilizing.");
           return false;
       }
```

with MinHook ?

Thank you !